# Flask 404 when using SERVER_NAME

Tags: python, apache, flask

In my Flask config, I'm setting SERVER_NAME to a domain like "app.example.com". I'm doing that because I need to use `url_for` with  `_external` URLs. If SERVER_NAME is not set, Flask thinks the server is 127.0.0.1:5000 (it's actually running behind a reverse-proxy), and returns an external URL like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/location`.

So far so good. But here's my problem: With SERVER_NAME set, every URL returns 404. I see each request hitting the server, to the correct URL, but Flask responds with a 404. If I disable SERVER_NAME, the correct page is returned.

I'm using Apache with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse (I know, I'd rather use Nginx, but it's a requirement). Here are the headers I'm adding:

```
Header add Host "app.example.com"
RequestHeader set Host "app.example.com"

Header add X-Forwarded-Host "app.example.com"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Host "app.example.com"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just found the answer. Apache has an option called `ProxyPreserveHost`. Once it's set to On, everything works as expected.

More information here: http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2011/3/14/problem-with-apache-proxy-and-canonical-urls/

Comment: Good find! And this is the fix for nginx: `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: You might also need `proxy_redirect off;` for nginx

Comment: @PieterEnnes you should definitely make that an answer this is exactly what I needed thanks

Comment: It would be nice if the poster edited his answer to include @PieterEnnes answer for nginx, as it does indeed work.

Comment: If you have a port in your address and use `nginx`, you may want to use `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` as `$http_host` includes the port.