# Flask's built-in server always 404 with SERVER_NAME set

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, http-status-code-404, werkzeug

Here is a minimal example:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'myapp.dev:5000'


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    print(str(error))
    return '404', 404


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If I set `SERVER_NAME`, Flask would response *every* URL with a 404 error, and when I comment out that line, it functions correctly again.

```
/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/flask/bin/python3.6 /Users/sunqingyao/Projects/play-ground/python-playground/foo/foo.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 422-505-438
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2017 07:19:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Please note that this is not a duplicate of [Flask 404 when using SERVER_NAME](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22315887/5399734), since I'm not using Apache or any production web server. I'm just dealing with Flask's built-in development server.

I'm using Python 3.6.2, Flask 0.12.2, Werkzeug 0.12.2, PyCharm 2017.2.3 on macOS High Sierra, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 7):

When set SERVER_NAME, you should make HTTP request header 'Host' the same with it:

```
# curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/ -sv -H 'Host: myapp.dev:5000'
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Accept: */*
> Host: myapp.dev:5000
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 13
< Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.5
< Date: Thu, 14 Jun 2018 09:34:31 GMT
<
* Closing connection 0
Hello, World!
```

if you use web explorer， you should access it use http://myapp.dev:5000/ and set /etc/hosts file.

It is like the nginx vhost, use Host header to do routing.

I think The SERVER_NAME is mainly used for route map.

you should set host and ip by hand

> app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=5000)

if you not set host/ip but set SERVER_NAME and found it seems to work,because the app.run() have this logic:

```
    def run(self, host=None, port=None, debug=None,
        load_dotenv=True, **options):

        ...

        _host = '127.0.0.1'
        _port = 5000
        server_name = self.config.get('SERVER_NAME')
        sn_host, sn_port = None, None

        if server_name:
            sn_host, _, sn_port = server_name.partition(':')

        host = host or sn_host or _host
        port = int(port or sn_port or _port)

        ...

        try:
            run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
        finally:
            self._got_first_request = False
```

At last, don't use SERVER_NAME to set host,ip app.run() used, unless you know its impact on the route map.

Comment: Hi, this is not the case as of 2019/08 (Flask 1.0), default host and port of run command are hardcoded. https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/c478e5d52f4985a9a58f1ac1d229b47e9f6fe24f/src/flask/cli.py#L780-L781

Comment: Thank u so much i was breaking my head with this problem ! up vote for the plus explanation ! THANKS !

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I find Flask's docs to be confusing (see the quotes above by @dm295 - the meaning of the implications surrounding 'SERVER_NAME' is hard to parse). But an alternative setup to (and inspired by) @Dancer Phd's answer is to specify the 'HOST' and 'PORT' parameters in a config file instead of 'SERVER_NAME'.

For example, let's say you use this config strategy proposed in the Flask [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/), add the host & port number like so:

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://:memory:'
    HOST = 'http://localhost' #
    PORT = '5000'

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user@localhost/foo'

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True

class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
```

Comment: Where is this documented? Did you actually get it to work? Why does HOST include `http://`?

Comment: Hi @BigMcLargeHuge, please see this section on the linked docs: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/config/#development-production. I don't think you need `http://` in localhost, it should work either way

Comment: Specifically, I was asking about the HOST and PORT values. I can't find any documentation for either of those settings.

Comment: Ah I see. I think the Flask docs have since changed. From a comment to [this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50854646/1145905), it appears that the default values for 'host' and 'port' are `127.0.0.1` and `5000`, respectively. Actually, to run my app on the CLI I typically do: `flask run --host=localhost --port=PORT_NUMBER`

Answer (score 1):

From [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/):

> the name and port number of the server. Required for subdomain support
>   (e.g.: 'myapp.dev:5000') Note that localhost does not support
>   subdomains so setting this to “localhost” does not help. Setting a
>   SERVER_NAME also by default enables URL generation without a request
>   context but with an application context.

and

> More on SERVER_NAME
>
> The SERVER_NAME key is used for the subdomain
>   support. Because Flask cannot guess the subdomain part without the
>   knowledge of the actual server name, this is required if you want to
>   work with subdomains. This is also used for the session cookie.
>
> Please keep in mind that not only Flask has the problem of not knowing
>   what subdomains are, your web browser does as well. Most modern web
>   browsers will not allow cross-subdomain cookies to be set on a server
>   name without dots in it. So if your server name is 'localhost' you
>   will not be able to set a cookie for 'localhost' and every subdomain
>   of it. Please choose a different server name in that case, like
>   'myapplication.local' and add this name + the subdomains you want to
>   use into your host config or setup a local bind.

It looks like there's no point to setting it to `localhost`. As suggested in the docs, try something like `myapp.dev:5000`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use just port number and host inside of the `app.run` like:

```
app.run(debug=True, port=5000, host="localhost")
```

Delete:

```
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'myapp.dev:5000'
```

Answer (score -3):

Using `debug=True` worked for me:

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'localhost:5000'

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```